# How to make a regex for textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this code

```
var message_regex = /^.{10,500}$/;
```

I want the user to enter a minimum of `10` characters, But it doesn't matter how much words I enter my error code still shows up.
If I remove the `500` from the code above everything works fine. I just want to know if my `regex` code is fine or am I missing something?
This is my `jquery` code for the `regex`

```
if(message == ""){
    $(".val_message").html("Please enter an inquiry").addClass('validate');
    validation_holder = 1;
} else {
    if(!message_regex.test(message)) {
        $(".val_message").html("Your message is too short please enter atleast 10 characters").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    } else {
    $(".val_message").html("");
    }
  }
```

Also if I put change the code to

```
var message_regex   = /^.{5,500}$/;
```

It doesn't care if I enter one character. What could be wrong?

Comment: The problem could be because of new line character .... `(/^.{10,500}$/m).test('01234567800\n999')` returns false

Comment: i think it has to do something with your message display is it css set to display block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need regex for this. This validation can be done like this also:

```
// assuming ta is your textarea element
var maxlen = 500;
var minlen = 5;
if(ta.value.length > maxlen) { 
    $(".val_message").html("Enter at most " + maxlen + " characters in the textarea");
    ta.value = ta.value.substr(0, maxlen); 
}
else if(ta.value.length < minlen) { 
   $(".val_message").html("Enter at least " + minlen + " characters in the textarea");
}
```

Comment: Can your code work to make a character counter like the one on the bottom of this comments `textarea`??

Comment: This answer is for validation of maxlen and minlen as you've shown in your question also. There are so many samples out there to create character counter for a `textarea`.

Answer (score 1):

i think the regex should look like this

```
var messageregex = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{10}*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem guys. I feel so dumb!! Probably cause it's 3 am.

```
<textarea id="message" class="cfMsg" name="message" placeholder="Your inquiry"></textarea>
```

My problem was the `name="message"` I had it like `name="name"` when I changed it my regex coded worked :/ Sorry! and thanks for the help I learned a new way of doing it from @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it would probably be easiest to use the `minlength` and `maxlength` attributes on the `textarea`, which have been available for many years now:

```html
<textarea
  id="message"
  class="cfMsg"
  name="message"
  minlength="10"
  maxlength="500"
  placeholder="Your inquiry"></textarea>
```

The only downside is that [IE does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#browser_compatibility) `minlength`, but that might not be a problem these days.